# Show image stored in array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, image, drop-down-menu, background-image

I'm doing an exercice for my web developement class, but I'm stuck. Here's the problem:
- I have a multiple choice menu. When the user selects "music" I want to show him three  each one containing an image with the background-image CSS propriety. The images must be stored in a php array.
The same needs to happen when the user chooses "sport" or "theatre".

The problem is that when I try to show the images stored in the array, I can see only the written link (ex. "www.pexels.com") and not the image itself.

If anyone can help me, it would be really appreciated, thanks!

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Devoir 1 de php</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Catégorie:</h1>


      <?php
        include "data.php";

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

         switch($_POST["activite"])
         {
            case 'musique':
            $image1 = $musique['imageMusique1'];
            $image2 = $musique['imageMusique2'];
            $image3 = $musique['imageMusique1'];
            break;

            case 'théâtre';
            echo "théâtre";
            break;

            case 'sport':
            echo "Sport";
            break;
          }

        }
      ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
      <select name="activite" >
        <option value="musique">Musique</option>
        <option value="théâtre">Théâtre</option>
        <option value="sport">Sport</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="voir photos" name="submit">
    </form>


    <div style = "background-image: url('<?php echo $image1 ?>')"></div>
    <div style = "background-image: url(<?php echo $image2 ?>)"></div>
    <div style = "background-image: url(<?php echo $image3 ?>)"></div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for the page storing the arrays (they must be separate for the exercise).

```html
<?php

$musique = array('imageMusique1' => 'image_musique1.jpg' , 'imageMusique2' => '../images/images_theatre/image_musique2.jpg', 'imageMusique3' => '../images/images_theatre/image_musique3.jpg' );
$theatre = array('imageTheatre1' => '' , 'imageTheatre2' => '', 'imageTheatre3' => '' );
$sport = array('imageSport1' => '' , 'imageSport2' => '', 'imageSport3' => '' );


echo $musique['imageMusique1'];


?>
```

Comment: Why a background image? Use a img tag inside the div

Answer (score 1):

Your div has no space to display the image.

As for example, set the width and height and try:

```
<div style = "background-image: url('<?php echo $image1 ?>'); width:100px;height:100px"></div>
```

Of course, the size of the div must match your expectations.

As an alternative, you can use `<img />` instead.